# error in Terminal when trying to install textmate bundle from github

Tags: github, terminal, coffeescript, textmate, powerpc

I'm trying to install the [Coffeescript bundle](https://github.com/jashkenas/coffee-script-tmbundle) into TextMate via terminal.

I cd to the correct directory but when I try the git command I get:

"Launch of "git" failed: the PowerPC architecture is no longer supported." I imagine that's because I upgraded to Lion. But this seems ridiculous that I can't git anymore.

And manual install doesn't work because the bundle is a group of folders, not a single file like all the other bundles in the Bundles section of the application.

Any suggestions?

Thanks,
Charlie Magee

Comment: Something wrong with your git install. Try [homebrew](http://mxcl.github.com/homebrew/) to reinstall it (`brew install git`).

Comment: I can't install homebrew. I can't update git. I can't use curl or svn. All return error of "the PowerPC architecture is no longer supported." When I go to the git download page for OSX there is no version for Lion. What the?

Comment: you don't need special versions for Lion, the "Universal" binary is what you should look for. Apparently you have way deeper issues with your system than merely installing textmate bundles... try a fresh install.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need Git to install a TextMate bundle:

1. download the .zip from github
2. extract it
3. rename the folder to `coffeescript.tmbundle`
4. double-click on it to install it automatically
5. done

Your Git problem is probably because your `git` is a PowerPC executable *or* an universal executable. You should re-install it.

A few things are missing from your question: When/how did you install `git`? Do you use it often? Does it work elsewhere? What was the previous version of your OS?

Comment: Thanks Romaini. That worked. I'd never seen that trick before, about renaming a folder like that. I installed git a few years ago, but don't use it often. It was working fine before I upgraded to Lion. Previous version was Snow Leopard, can't remember the actual number.

Comment: I don't know how old this trick is but it has been working for a long time.